# Convert SQL query to ActiveRecord Query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, active-record-query

I have a SQL query that I am running on a SQLite database.  It works fine to retrieve records in a date range for Saturday & Sunday between 7AM and 6PM.

When I run the query it returns an array of hashes.  I want to convert it to an ActiveRecord Query so it returns an array of objects that I can more easily operate on.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from reports where datetime between '2015-03-25' and '2015-04-12' and strftime('%w', datetime) IN ('0','6') and strftime('%H', datetime) >= '07' and strftime('%H:%M', datetime)
```

I've looked at the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and am uncertain how to go about this, any help would be very much appreciated!

**Update:**
Getting pretty close with this:

```
Report.where("datetime >= ? AND datetime <= ?", '2015-03-25 21:15:00', '2015-04-27 07:56:00').where("cast(strftime('%H', datetime) as int) >= ? AND cast(strftime('%H', datetime) as int) <= ?", 07,17).where("cast(strftime('%w', datetime) as int) = ?", 0)
```

Still need to sneak in the option of 1 (in addition to 0) on the last where clause.  I am guessing it could be cleaned up as well.  Still open to input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this complicated SQL query string, I think you should use `find_by_sql` of `ActiveRecord`. Document here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql.

```
Report.find_by_sql("select * from reports where datetime between '2015-03-25' and '2015-04-12' and strftime('%w', datetime) IN ('0','6') and strftime('%H', datetime) >= '07' and strftime('%H:%M', datetime)
```